# Accessing public array list in setPositiveButton OnClick Function

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog, android-contextmenu

I am currently having issues accessing `public array list` in an `setPositiveButton onClick` function. accessing it with this doesn't work. Here is my code:

**Declaring the array list with title modules.**

```
public class DisplayModulesActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<Modules> modules;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_modules);

        modules = new ArrayList<Modules>();
        modules.add(new Modules("387COM Smartphone App Development"));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.moduleList);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Modules>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, modules);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

I want to access the array list here and remove something from it **(line with modules.remove(i);** it does not work.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_module) {
        AlertDialog.Builder confirmDel = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        confirmDel
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this module and all its contents?");
        confirmDel.setCancelable(true);
        confirmDel.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                            int i) {
                        Log.v("Test", "Confirm Delete YES pressed");
                        // AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                        // (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)
                        // item.getMenuInfo();
                        // int i = info.position;
                        modules.remove(i);
                        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        confirmDel.setNegativeButton("No", null);

        confirmDel.show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas please?

**FIX**

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    final int arrayItem = info.position;

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_module)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder confirmDel = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        confirmDel.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this module and all its contents?");
        confirmDel.setCancelable(true);
        confirmDel.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Log.v("Test", "Confirm Delete YES pressed");

                modules.remove(arrayItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        confirmDel.setNegativeButton("No", null);

        confirmDel.show();
    }
```

Comment: please change to final ArrayList<Modules> modules;

Comment: @Krishna 'final ArrayList<Modules> modules =  new ArrayList<Modules>();' if i make it like this, it still breaks just after the alert button press

Comment: add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after listview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: @Krishna still breaks in the same place

Comment: post your `onItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is, that `i` is not the `position` of the item in the `ArrayList` `modules`.
It is the `position` of the positive button (which might be 0 or 1 or 2 on every click, no matter which icon; maybe it's -1).

To fix this problem do the following:

Save/use the `position` given in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` and somehow pass it through to the `onClickListener()` of the dialog. Use this position to remove an item from your `modules` list.

E.g. in `onItemClick()` save `position` to a filed of your class `mClickedPosition` and call `modules.remove(mClickedPosition)` in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your code:

```
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Modules>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,modules);

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

do this ;)

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_module)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder confirmDel = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    confirmDel.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this module and all its contents?");
    confirmDel.setCancelable(true);
    confirmDel.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            Log.v("Test", "Confirm Delete YES pressed");
            //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            //int i = info.position;
            modules.remove(i);
             adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Modules>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,modules);

             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
    confirmDel.setNegativeButton("No", null);

    confirmDel.show();
}
```

Comment: i had to change your code to 'adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Modules>(DisplayModulesActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,modules);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);' since it cannot resolve constructor that way, even though it still breaks after the button press...